# Como localizar 2 correspondências que se intercalam com um mesmo regex

Tags: c#, regex

Na seguinte string:

> 83/80/95

Preciso que encontre `83/80` e `80/95`, usando o mesmo regex.
Estou usando o seguinte regex:

```
(\d{2,4})[\/](\d{2,4})
```

O primeiro `Match` "83/80" é encontrado, mas o segundo não.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não tem como fazer isso com uma única regex **processando a string de uma vez** (ou seja, com uma única chamada ao [método `Match`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8)), pois a regex vai avaliando da esquerda para a direita, sempre avançando na string. Uma vez encontrado um *match*, o próximo será buscado a partir da posição posterior ao último encontrado, ou seja, após encontrar o `80`, ela começará a busca a partir de `/95`.

Então o jeito é ir "cortando" a string original, eliminando somente a parte antes da barra, e procurar pela regex nesta string "cortada":

```
string s = "83/80/95";
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2,4}/\d{2,4}");
while (s.Length >= 5)
{
    Match m = regex.Match(s);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('/') + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Ou seja, neste *loop* eu faço a busca e imprimo o *match* encontrado. Em seguida, eu uso `Substring` para pegar o trecho da string depois da primeira barra, e faço a busca novamente nesta substring.

Na primeira iteração, a busca será feita na string toda, e será encontrado `83/80`. Em seguida, `Substring` irá retornar todo o trecho depois da primeira barra (ou seja, agora a string é `"80/95"`, e na próxima iteração a regex fará a busca nesta string, encontrando `80/95`.

Quando a regex não encontra mais nenhum *match* (ou quando a substring encontrada tem tamanho menor que 5), o loop é interrompido. Coloquei a condição `while (s.Length >= 5)` porque a regex precisa que existam pelo menos 5 caracteres para que seja encontrado um *match* (`\d{2,4}` é "no mínimo 2 e no máximo 4 dígitos", então o mínimo que a string precisa é de 5 caracteres: dois dígitos, uma barra e mais dois dígitos - se tiver menos que 5 caracteres, nem preciso tentar usar a regex e já posso interromper o *loop*).

A saída do código é:

```
83/80
80/95
```

Repare também que na regex a barra não precisa ser escrita como `[\/]`, pode escrever simplesmente `/`. Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): por exemplo, `[ab]` significa "a letra `a` ou a letra `b`" (qualquer uma delas), então `[\/]` significa "o caractere `/`", que você trocar pelo próprio caractere `/` (não há ganho em usar os colchetes nesse caso, então pode removê-los).

Também retirei os parênteses em volta do `\d{2,4}`, já que eles [formam um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e como você quer todo o *match* (e não somente um grupo), eles também não são necessários.